# sum of noncentral Chi-square random variables

Tags: distributions, random-variable, chi-squared-distribution, non-central, saddlepoint-approximation

I need to find the distribution of the random variable 
$$Y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i)^2$$
where $X_i\sim{\cal{N}}(\mu_i,\sigma^2_i)$ and all $X_i$s are independent. I know that it is possible to first find the product of all moment generating functions for $X_i$s, and then transform back to obtain $Y$'s distribution. However, I wonder whether there is a general form for $Y$ like the Gaussian case: we know the sum of independent Gaussian is still a Gaussian, and thus we only need to know the summed mean and summed variance.

How about all $\sigma^2_i=\sigma^2$? Will this condition make a general solution?

Comment: Looking at the first paragraph under [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution#Background), clearly the final condition yields a scaled noncentral chi-square (divide through by $\sigma^2$ (the scale factor you take out the front) and make $\sigma_i=1$ in $\sum_{i=1}^k (X_i/\sigma_i)^2$). The more general form you started with looks like a linear combination or scaled-weighted-average, with coefficients $\sigma^2_i$ rather than a plain sum of scaled squares ... and I believe that won't generally have the required distribution.

Comment: Depending on what you need it for, in specific cases you may be able to do numerical convolution, or simulation.

Comment: This is generalized by the 'weighted sum of log chi-squares to power' distribution. My R package `sadists` provides approximate 'dpqr' functions for $Y$; _c.f._ https://github.com/shabbychef/sadists

Comment: @shabbychef thank you for your work!

Answer (score 23):

As Glen_b noted in the comments, if the variances are all the same you end up with a scaled noncentral chi-squared.

If not, there is a concept of a [generalized chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution), i.e. $x^T A x$ for $x \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ and $A$ fixed. In this case, you have the special case of diagonal $\Sigma$ ($\Sigma_{ii} = \sigma_i^2$), and $A = I$.

There has been some work on computing things with this distribution:

- [Imhof (1961)](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/48/3-4/419.extract) and [Davies (1980)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2346911) numerically invert the characteristic function.
- [Sheil and O'Muircheartaigh (1977)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2346884) write the distribution as an infinite sum of central chi-squared variables.
- [Kuonen (1999)](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/86/4/929) gives a saddlepoint approximation to the pdf/cdf.
- [Liu, Tang and Zhang (2009)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947308005653) approximate it with a noncentral chi-squared distribution based on cumulant matching.

You can also write it as a linear combination of independent noncentral chi-squared variables $Y = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2 \left( \frac{X_i^2}{\sigma_i^2} \right)$, in which case:

- [Castaño-Martínez and López-Blázquez (2005)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02595410) give a Laguerre expansion for the pdf/cdf.

[Bausch (2013)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.2691.pdf) gives a more computationally efficient algorithm for the linear combination of central chi-squareds; his work might be extensible to noncentral chi-squareds, and you might find some interesting pointers in the related work section.

Comment: A comparison of approximation methods is found in Duchesne et al. 2010. Computational Statistics and Data Analysis, 54, 858–862. The authors maintain the R package [CompQuadForm](http://cran.r-project.org/package=CompQuadForm) with implementations.