# The square root of weighted sum of chi-squared distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, chi-squared-distribution, chi-distribution

Let $X\sim\chi_m^2$ and $Y\sim\chi_n^2$ be two independent variables. How to calculate or estimate the expectation of $\sqrt{aX+bY}$, where $a,b>0$?

Comment: I assume that a and b are known values.

Comment: Yes, $a$ and $b$ are known.

Comment: Then the given answer by Dougal is excellent.

Answer (score 6):

$\chi_m^2$ variables are also known as $\Gamma(m/2, 2)$, using the shape-scale parameterization of the [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).

Scaled gamma distributions [are themselves gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Scaling), with the scale parameter scaled equally. So $a X \sim \Gamma(m / 2, 2 a)$, $b Y \sim \Gamma(n / 2, 2 b)$.

The sum of independent gammas *with the same scale* is itself gamma, so that if $b = a$, then $a X + a Y \sim \Gamma(\frac{n+m}{2}, 2 a)$. In that case, its square root is a [Nakagami distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakagami_distribution), with mean
$$\mathbb E \sqrt{a X + a Y} = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+m+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n+m}{2})} \sqrt{2 a}.$$

If $a \ne b$, I don't think there's such a neat answer. You can find or approximate the distribution of $a X + b Y$ in various ways, outlined in [the answers to this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479/general-sum-of-gamma-distributions):

- [whuber's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/72486/9964) gives a way to get the exact distribution which you could numerically integrate to get the expected square root.
- [kjetil's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/137318/9964) gives code for a numerical approximation to the pdf, which again you could numerically integrate for the expected square root.
- [Paul's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/191912/9964) uses the [Welch-Satterthwaite equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%E2%80%93Satterthwaite_equation) to approximate the sum as a gamma. Using that approximation, we get

  $$a X + b Y \stackrel{approx}{\sim} \Gamma\left( \frac{(m a + n b)^2}{2 (m a^2 + n b^2)}, 2 \frac{m a^2 + n b^2}{m a + n b} \right)$$

  which leads to

  $$
  \mathbb E \sqrt{a X + b Y} \approx \frac{\Gamma\left( \frac{(m a + n b)^2}{2 (m a^2 + n b^2)} + \frac12 \right)}{\Gamma\left( \frac{(m a + n b)^2}{2 (m a^2 + n b^2)} \right)} \sqrt{ 2 \frac{m a^2 + n b^2}{m a + n b}}
  .$$

In any case, you should probably check your answer against a simple Monte Carlo simulation for the parameters you're interested in.

Comment: Is there any analysis on the accuracy of Welch-Satterthwaite approximation?

Comment: @user07001129 I don't know of any offhand, and didn't find any in quick googling, though I didn't look very hard or read the original papers: https://dx.doi.org/10.2307%2F3002019 and https://dx.doi.org/10.2307%2F2332510, which may have some. I'd again recommend computing some Monte Carlo estimates for a few parameter values that you care about and seeing how they line up with the approximate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Danica provides several approaches for obtaining the distribution of $aX +bY$. This expression typically arises as the quadratic form in normal random variables. For completeness, I would like to add some additional approaches for computing $aX + bX$ numerically, which could then be used to calculate the expected square root numerically.

Imhof (1961) (https://www.jstor.org/stable/2332763) provides an exact numerical method, for which there is an R package available [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/CompQuadForm/man/imhof.html).

Bodemham and Adams (2016) (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-015-9583-4) evaluates the accuracy of 6 different approximations, including the Satterthwaite-Welch approximation. These are less accurate than Imhof's method, but generally considerably less computationally intensive, e.g. they found that the Satterthwaite-Welch approximation is abouth 50 times faster than Imhof's method. There is an associated Python package called momentchi2 available [here](https://pypi.org/project/momentchi2/).

In my experience Imhof's method is sufficiently fast for 10 to 20  terms, even when I use it in Monte Carlo simulations.

Also see  @Danica's answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67533/sum-of-noncentral-chi-square-random-variables/96953#96953), which refers to an approximate approach by Bausch (2013) (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.2691.pdf) suitable when the number of terms are large.