# What is the distribution of $(X−Y)^2+(Z−Y)^2$, where $X$,$Y$ and $Z$ are independent normal distributions with their own means and variance?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, convolution, chi-squared-distribution

I came up with a question: What is the distribution of $(X−Y)^2+(Z−Y)^2$, where $X$,$Y$ and $Z$ are independent normal distributions with their own means and variance? The common part is $Y$ in both of the summands that introduces correlations, otherwise it is χ2. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How does the histogram look like if you sample, say $10^5$, observations from $X, Y, Z$, compute and plot that expression? Maybe you can guess from that empirical data.

Comment: @Xi'an HI, i think the link you provided works only for independent variables, but in my case they are not.

Comment: The highly upvoted answer by djs there points out that this is a generalized chi-squared distribution and offers links to literature.

Comment: Dear whuber, I don't find the answer by djs. Could you please help? Thanks.

Comment: The answer by djs is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67533/sum-of-noncentral-chi-square-random-variables/96953#96953).