# Confidence interval for the norm of linear model coefficient vector

Tags: regression, confidence-interval

Given observed data from a normal model, $Y\sim N(X\beta, \sigma^2 I)$, where $X$ is a $n\times p$ matrix of known predictors, I want to compute a confidence interval for $||\beta||_2$, the L2 norm. I initially thought that I could invert the standard F-statistic -- $\hat{\beta}^\top(X^\top X)\hat{\beta}/(p\hat{\sigma}^2)$ has a non-central F distribution -- but the mapping from L2-norms to non-centrality parameters isn't one-to-one, so it seems this approach is bound to fail. Are there any standard methods for this?

My fallback would be to compute Bayesian credible intervals by sampling from a posterior distribution.

I should mention that in the intended application I expect the columns of $X$ to be weakly correlated, but I would be interested in a method that assumes orthogonality.

Comment: Bayesian posterior simulation provides a very simple answer...

Comment: Not a duplicate exactly, since $\sigma^2$ unknown, but it looks like there's no simple analytical solution here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/96953/87365.